# Angular spinning directive gets instantiated after controller load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller. Here is the relevant part of the constructor function (what is the correct term for this function?):

```
activate();

        function activate() {
            $scope.$broadcast('ctrlLoadingStarted');
                var promises = [getUsers()];
                return $q.all(promises).then(function (eventArgs) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('ctrlLoadingFinished');
            });
        }
```

So the activate function is basically a generic function that takes in an array of data getting functions. It broadcasts on start and broadcasts on finish.

Then I have a directive nested in the controllers scope, here is the relevant part of the directive:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('ctrlLoadingStarted', function (event, args) {
                scope.spinnerOn = true;
            });
            scope.$on('ctrlLoadingFinished', function (event, args) {
                scope.spinnerOn = false;
            });
        }
```

As you can see, it is simply listening to the start and finish events and turning a spinner on and off.

The issue is that the controller seems to be instantiating before the directive. This results in the broadcast going off and not turning the spinner on.

I tried to simply put `scope.spinnerOn = true;` in the first line of the directive (this way, no matter when the controller instantiates relative to the directive instantiation, the spinner will always go on). However, the problem I ran into there was that the controller's second broadcast would go out before the directive was instantiated as well causing an endless spinner.

I just want to ensure that if the controller instantiates before the directive but then the data-getting takes a while that the spinner will spin.

All advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the activate function in $timeout.

```
function activate() {
            $scope.$broadcast('ctrlLoadingStarted');
                var promises = [getUsers()];
                return $q.all(promises).then(function (eventArgs) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('ctrlLoadingFinished');
            });
        }

$timeout(activate)
```

With this the activate function will be called in next digest cycle.

More about Digest cycle `Integration with the browser event loop` section at: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

*Disclaimer: This is my understanding of how Javascript / browser works. It may not be correct.*

[image: How Javascript process our request]
[image: In your case]
[image: Solution]

Comment: I thought that I need to specify a time with $timeout as second parameter? What does $timeout do with no timeout specification? Can you expand on "next digest cycle"? The first digest cycle instantiates all objects? Is there always a second digest cycle when angular loads or does it only take place in a situation when there is a for example something on timeout?