# Controller included after $stateChangeSuccess is fired

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I have a menu navigation bar that is made of several accordion widgets, and uses ng-include to include every section of the menu separately.

Some of these sections contains sub-sections that are also included through ng-include.

The first level accordion successfully uses the

```
$rootScope.on('$stateChangeSuccess')
```

to open the corresponding section based on the url, so that for example if the user opens a page that is supposed to have a certain accordion opened, it will automatically open even if you reload the page or share the link. I used the same code in the inner controller to sync the inner accordion as well, but to no avail. It appears that the second controller is initialized after the event was already fired. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: This might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719257/4578788

Comment: @VinayK but I don't have any control over when the event is fired, ui-router does. Or are you suggesting I create my own events and use them?

Comment: Yes. Try with the custom events.

Comment: It works with custom events thanks.... But only works if I debug, as soon as I remove the breakpoints it won't work anymore unless I delay the timeout with something like 500 ms ........